# ExpandableListView top fading edge always visible

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an ExpandableListView with the following set as the style

```
<style name="expendable_list_view">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

Now, the bottom fading edge behaves normally, but the top one always fades to black.
I have tried setting

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

and again, only the bottom fading edge is gone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was somewhere else.

The ExpendableListView was loaded into the application using LocalActivityManager and it seems that all the Activities have some sort of transparent-to-black fade on the top. So I have simply changed the theme:

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

So, that solves the problem :)
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cache color hint to #00000000

Comment: It doesn't matter what I set the background color to, it might be transparent white or black or any random color. The border is there.